# What are PHP 5.2 settnigs which affect compatibility with old code (developed for PHP 4 and 3)?

Tags: php

What are PHP 5.2 settnigs which affect compatibility with old code (developed for PHP 4 and 3)?

A web application using XTemplate 0.2.4-2 (officially meant for 3.0.11) works fine on one server running PHP 5.2 but works incorrect (seems that the form can't be submitted or processed correctly) on new PHP 5.2 and 5.3 installations. What may I need to tweak on new servers to make them able to run legacy code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer that has solved my problem was register_globals = On. It seems to affect submits. If it is Off (defaut for PHP 5), then a form in a XTemplate 0.2.4-2 can not be submitted correctly. Thanks Warren Benedetto for this suggestion.